# symbol(s) not found for architecture i386?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I am trying to implement a map with multiple marker. But i get stacked on this error.

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

```
  "_xmlFreeDoc", referenced from:

      +[MTDXMLElement nodesForXPathQuery:onXML:namespacePrefix:namespaceURI:] in MTDirectionsKit(MTDXMLElement.o)

  "_xmlReadMemory", referenced from:

      +[MTDXMLElement nodesForXPathQuery:onXML:namespacePrefix:namespaceURI:] in MTDirectionsKit(MTDXMLElement.o)
  "_xmlXPathEvalExpression", referenced from:

      +[MTDXMLElement mtd_nodesForXPathQuery:namespacePrefix:namespaceURI:libXMLDoc:] in MTDirectionsKit(MTDXMLElement.o)

  "_xmlXPathFreeContext", referenced from:

      +[MTDXMLElement mtd_nodesForXPathQuery:namespacePrefix:namespaceURI:libXMLDoc:] in MTDirectionsKit(MTDXMLElement.o)
  "_xmlXPathFreeObject", referenced from:

      +[MTDXMLElement mtd_nodesForXPathQuery:namespacePrefix:namespaceURI:libXMLDoc:] in MTDirectionsKit(MTDXMLElement.o)
  "_xmlXPathNewContext", referenced from:

      +[MTDXMLElement mtd_nodesForXPathQuery:namespacePrefix:namespaceURI:libXMLDoc:] in MTDirectionsKit(MTDXMLElement.o)
  "_xmlXPathRegisterNs", referenced from:

      +[MTDXMLElement mtd_nodesForXPathQuery:namespacePrefix:namespaceURI:libXMLDoc:] in MTDirectionsKit(MTDXMLElement.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Someone can explain me what is it telling by "symbol(s) not found for architecture i386".

Answer (score 0):

Your library, MTDirectionsKit doesn't support the simulator. Depending where you got the library, you will either have to rebuild it into a universal library, or include (and properly configure your build settings) the static library for the Simulator (Debug-Simulator).

Xcode 4 stopped building static universal libraries. So depending on the developer, they are not building as one, but 4 separate libraries. You can bundle them into 1, but you need to add the build script to take care of it.